# Is this a valid arrow function?

Tags: javascript

This question is from an online quiz and I'm confused by it. I feel its the third one but I get undefined.

Which choice is an example of an arrow function, if c is defined in the outer scope.

```
                a,b =>c;
                {a,b} => c;
                (a,b) =>c;  //this one.
                a,b => {return c;}
```

Comment: Yes, the third one.

Comment: What happened when you tried each of those examples in your browser?

Comment: Note that only the second one has invalid syntax. The first and last one are valid, and employ the comma operator, with the arrow function being the right hand operand.

Answer (score 2):

The question is primarily asking about *syntax*.  The third option is indeed the correct choice, because the function parameters `a` and `b` must be enclosed in parenthesis `(` and `)`.

You get `undefined` because `c` must first be defined.

```js
var c = 'foo';       // define c in outer scope
var f = (a,b) => c;  // define the arrow function
var result = f(1,2); // invoke the arrow function with some parameters
console.log(result); // examine the output is 'foo', the value of c
```

Comment: Indeed. If an arrow function has only one parameter, putting parentheses around it is optional. If an arrow function has two or more parameters, or no parameters at all, parentheses will be required.

Answer (score 0):

Only the second one has invalid syntax.

The first and last one are also valid, and employ the comma operator, with the arrow function being the right hand operand. You'll still get a run time error if `a` is not a defined variable, but once it is, it is valid:

```js
let a; // define

a,b =>c; // valid
a,b => {return c;} // valid

console.log("ok");
```

The third one would be the evident choice; it is also the only valid arrow function that does not need `a` to be defined in the outer scope.

If you *call* these valid functions, then `c` needs to be defined, which seems to be guaranteed.

Comment: Very nice catch. :) Usage of the comma operator seems to be a valid scenario indeed, but it would also be a rather exotic one for a JavaScript quiz targeting beginning JavaScript developers. :) Regarding `c`, the question already states that that binding is defined in the outer scope. That's not the case for `a`, however. ;)